# Distinguishing between the hold and release of a modifier key between two keystrokes in Vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I'd like to make a mapping in Vim so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> switches to the previous buffer (`:b#`), but then if <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed again without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, switches to the next buffer (`:bn`) instead.

This is similar to how the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> function in MS Windows works. Is there any way to achieve this effect?
I can't seem to find this question asked anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim only processes complete key presses; there's only a slight semantic difference in `<LeftMouse>` vs. `<LeftRelease>`. You somehow need to process the key chording into different, separate keystrokes (maybe some unused `<F13>` key?), and can then `:map` that inside Vim. On Windows, the [AutoHotkey tool](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will let you achieve that.

Alternatively, you could `:nmap <C-Tab>`, and check whether the previous invocation has happened only recently (using `localtime()`). That should give you something that works practically as you want.

Comment: I got a fairly elegant solution to this with the AutoHotkey mapping `~Ctrl up::send {F13}` and a small vimscript that maps <C-Tab> and <F13>. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, that looks good and is what I had in mind. Thanks for posting your full solution; others may be interested in it, too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vimscript I wrote, for anyone interested. I used AutoHotkey to map the release of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>F13</kbd>. (See Ingo Karkat's answer)

```
let g:ctrl_held = 0
let g:prev_buf = 1
function! Ctrltab()
   if g:ctrl_held == 0
      let cmd = ":b".g:prev_buf."\<CR>"
      if g:prev_buf == bufnr('')
         let cmd = ":bn\<CR>"
      endif
      let g:prev_buf = bufnr('') 
      let g:ctrl_held = 1
      return cmd
   else
      return ":bn\<CR>"
   endif
endfunction
nmap <expr> <C-Tab> Ctrltab()
nmap <silent> <F13> :let g:ctrl_held = 0<CR>
```